# How to Preview and download a PDF in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to read a PDF from the azure blob (Which i was successful in that) and got the below pdf content.
Problem : I am trying to preview this content in a modal and download it in a pdf document when i click a button.

To get into the below format i had used the below code to convert:

```
// Download and convert a blob to a string
const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
const downloaded = await streamToBuffer(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody);
console.log("Downloaded blob content:", downloaded.toString());

async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const chunks = [];
readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
});
readableStream.on("end", () => {
resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
});
readableStream.on("error", reject);
});
}
```

```
P!ߤ�lZ[Content_Types].xml �(����n�0E�����Ub袪*�>�-R�{V��Ǽ��QU�
l"%3��3Vƃ�ښl    �w%�=���^i7+���-d&�0�A�6�l4��L60#�Ò�S
O����X��*��V$z�3��3������%p)O�
                              ���5}nH"d�s�Xg�L�`���|�ԟ�|�P�rۃs��?�PW��tt4Q+��"�wa���|T\y���,N���U�%���-D/��ܚ��X�ݞ�(���<E��)��;�N�L?�F�˼��܉��<Fk��h�y����ڜ���q�i��?�ޯl��i�1��]�H�g��m�@����m���P!���N
                                                 _rels/.rels �(����j�0
��      ��^�[��x����1x�p�                                             @���ѽQ���N/c��[IL��j���<��]�aG��ӓ�zs�Fu��]��U
                         ���f��#I)ʃ�Y���������*D��
                                                  i")��c$���qU���~3��1��jH[{�=E����~
f?��3-���޲]�Tꓸ2�j)�,l0/%��b�
���z���ŉ�,      �       �/�|f\Z���?6�!Y�_�o]A���P!B:O}��
word/document.xml���n� ��+�,�'�����n�d�(R�FM�,�6��S����m�F^��|�
                                                               È�=/�-U��j�����Њ��U��������u��U�KQх{�ڽY~�p�KRA6�V�D���$
                                                                                                                      �0FiRP��%gD       -2sIG"��h'T����T�P�a�;\m�v[ُ��
���#D
�
 ��
   �l�
      }B�!(�������U5E�@�j@�M#�r�x)�����!i>�'>
                                             p!i��Pq�^6��f%3`zq���z����g�)-ô����QU��_�����o��B�9c�j�C}r�h       ��.�<�p>��Eپu�-/�u;�|.�KO�ƕ=p�����l��M��7bG�1�޳S�!
��'��Ĺ���� &td���H�B-��|���a�c��y�_1'M�C�:��ON$�������h�}�����6�O��~���K�M�$�y%^��فxt�%\���&�;6�K���Ez����(�X�G��>���[��QH�ƎFq�`�       |��
                                                                                                                                           ����y��V4Û��/
[c# +�Q�D��0}w-���4;�-(N)�����fB��n���AU���Q-1�͚z>��z;)YE��!�2��Y��n6�G�r���P!�d�Q�word/_rels/document.xml.rels �(����j�0E�����}-;}PB�lJ!���E?�, ��`HI��`��r��sπ6����w��{���r茯{�*x���AkWk�*�`[^^l��jNK���D�8R�1���d:4e>�K/����4�Vm^u�r��w2NP�0ŮVw�5�j
                                                                                                    ��o����7o:>S!?p����8JX[d�0KD��EVK���c2�P,���ũ�a���]���.���ﰘs�Yҡ�+�����(!O>z���P!��g��� word/theme/theme1.xml�YK������z��a�5�H�k�6޵���Rk���i��ڵ0�`�r  ��C
                                                                                                           ��B
                                                                                                              1��c�I���I3-�ď]�  ��U?�������4s����:G�
   �[=Wq��ؘ$aǽ}0,�\GH��e �
                         ,܋;�v�����8�:n$��|�,F0��96� �M���.�c��AoL˵J�Q�I\'A1��1��v�Jwg�|@�_"�Q��TcCBc�Ӫ�
                                                                                                        P�!�qa�1;>����P$$Lt܊�s�;�k!*
                                                                                                                                    dsrC���[
��5-��õ���^��֯Tn��Ac�X��4�NS.��f-��(mZt���z����׷�]_}
                                                   ��Mo
�(I�[�ߨ�ݮ!F/[�m�kKx�*�+�OdQ����Ch�"IG.fx�F�            ?�
                                           %��8�$� �f(a�+�ʰR������(:�QN:��!��#Nf��^�n��ŋ����|���Ǐ_>�u����e��y�7?}���/����͓o�x�ǿ�����_�A�g��?{�������rt���
       �:>vn�6hY���8��Kt�P�)
                            z #}}�(��zش����4�gޏ�\
�7)��8��Qsl��E�.!�]�Ȉ3�&ҹK�"V��C#�2��$�,l�߆m��8=Fm����D��@ԦSÌ��\����4��E2���_�ap!��!����6�aнi���=��M$�djC�"���>��gV�$���+b
!���LZI0�>�%��C���ې���f��v$03��N�)���H�]N��ћ�Fh�bL�1c�ܾbó�a����el��Udƪ�'X@���c�0Bv�����b#�,P#^����
                                                                                                  �\u�5^�hj�R�ա���!bc�ZoF+��x]p��r�@���������ζ9@�X 
  �U�-݂���LD'-6��M�C����Q��$yk�Q�����
��O-�өw���T:E�d��)�mV5�c��5}4Onb�G,г�欦���4E����9�d�*��G�d��E?Z=��Z�§>B�\P�+t�#�쏇0�;Zh��iAs���
                                                                                               9�m�3���~�f�LU����P83&�p��V�j���=6NG���sM@2�k5e�LG��Z���A늀�}��Lu
               ��j�-$��N�E�¢����_K���� �H��RFn�c�T~��S�t�1�m�,�k+���i�D.�L�0����>e_�3���)�i4[��*�l���=��\�5#4����x���T��I�ɥ�?$�̸�}$������Db�PC���@��[��T{�Dɵ+����W��x2�#Y0�ua.Ub�=!Xu�H�G�c���-��Ue�1rm�1��ά����G�xߒQDgZ�(�d��u{M'��tsWf���P9�ķ�ۅ�D.i\ �ִ珏w��Xey�`����\�^庢[��B�Z��AM1�P�FMj�X�[�f�qڷ�fԪ
����kbUW��֋mvx"���J��¯���+�4��Uv�/�9'�A��zA�J��?(yu�Rj��z�������V���C0��⪟�=��t�|o�Ƿ��ǫR�܈�e������w��<hԆ�z��(���a���Z�v���������>t�#
     Z�FJ^���ڥ�W�u�f�5�������W�ռv���P!Y��v
                                          word/settings.xml�V�o�6~�����I��fB�"��%E�U�=S"e�/��w���#%ZN3N����}w�y�;�����`G��R̢�"�DTS��E_V��h`,1)�,:}�������kA�
          �B��W�hk����T[��k�9��՛�#�بa%�B���Q{�GI2�:9�-�b�i����u&��kZ��/X�s��&KY5�=ƚ0�A
���6��ln��{��q��ir�q�R��9�9�eE��q��w<yAt�}��#z*0O�:�<{����"O���8b�<��u<�#�/6��X0'���"
                                                                                     q��Od�99n�{Zj���%�W��FH�J�@�������ݟ_��+x�_��}������
                                                                                                                                        $I;jHօE,sc�-T� p��7qx�A�m0�Q��*
                      +(���ݨ���H��](T�B
�%
  zX�)������,|��WE�v�B '|�J�Y����p�{����֑�6�)&�f
                                               {`d��+��cc,F�P~"��@���   j��Ȋ ��5��3���jM���N`��7sF�hp@���P>T˽��[�0L�7���7(�S?@Y>Υ�������2��=>-_��؄�nN�N�ԏs*^h/�)�2��ar�O�y��_:�\�xk�@��
                   �[�U����$�_�5қ�����+�n�����h٨�k���
                                                     *�d�YRa�)rӔE��O�F�O;�奔�}n!���#_^��ᗢ+�
                                                                                           �l�FJ�5Sn�Y��fkS�f
                                                                                                             ;
                                                                                                              �3~SnF6�ب��U�d��-z�(�N��A6�e� ���,Ȳ���m�KhhُP�a��dL�        ������)�l;:��l]�7�]N�`^L-|%*�9zr�c4u�6C��g�s��9Fu6~f�K��Xܤ�(�cq�e?@.��5���+u�~�X:ɱ������iz�Z���[8�3��~y�L�92wX0�Z�V��|�MF��"�N�t9�}�ʆKx��Y�ͧ��G>�����P!K�qal
                                  �rword/styles.xml��[sۺ��;����S���W9���$��v�O�4�       Y�AB�ŗ~� %A^��[�$�e����M�������P��h���(�Y��ݟ�~�}{�a%�&U��&�CQ��W)�Jι�D�U��R����)���X�KV����|��MF
              �,V��>�'�'�\ż(�F���Ldk���"�U���{�1M�,J���ٿR��0��3��a�u��  �3YsD�p�:�
�C��Q��f�����>S9�IM�Ez�#
                        6��ޚ�����MT���Y%�¼�o��e����Mee=��"�N�K�S�۹<�
�����ϯU���i�?8��?�ns�r�Fm���)OťH�9_�"�<�Y�d���߬��7bUe��Ó���H�>�|i���4cF��&@�oWbӸ�?8��z�2cΪR5�X@��;#�-�
��UCު!��6$��?�F���.�Ǎh��lh��Kh��*h��V    h�g��9�y��x�)�S��7
                                                          ��~�������0��]Bw� ��;�qw��0��t�ݝ�ø��5�[/��+m��첹Re�J��y8�e�e�H����d#  0ufkvăi1��w�k���yi
�Hͣ���r^
       �8��TK�$�<B`��*��HȜ����<�9�Ħ��J0ʪtF07�잌ų�x�VD����к~^�I��8Wû�Y~���2��s%%'b}��b�5�6��᥁�
                                                                                             �
�h�р54�q��'ո54�qkhD��І�۝(�M��c����                                                             ,fxa�hF5D
                                 �̑�����������Ms�4�e9���r����Xw���|V�KtG�O[����v�\�Y5|@�hT�Z���l��L6
                                                                                                   �K�zfZ��V�ZR/�N����p��r�
                                                                                                                           ����
                                                                                                                               2c       f�w��5rRd���R�4i��e�s]�=
[ޠ[�DF���w)2�[A\��\Gwji�L304�Ϫ,UJ�l���������^��������LMR        I/3E&H����O�2S,Ohh�9�/�)9q��e�� �΋O:���,�_,����H`�aâ�����S�w���*��G�Ե�t��˄-��%�US���%��-�����Qm�dE!��P�yT���Qo����)��y%�p$���Ҭ��b�#�`ˣ�^�)cy��,��H�İ0*%,�J
#Z80�yF��':����晅Q�3                                                     ����H~�����N
                    ��gF5��D|>׋`�]����s�nG��<]���/Dȯ��3��5�6Wss���ꋸ    ���$\l�8*��Y�
                                                                                     ��_GD��J[��pl���k�����p+Y�J&<�l�?V�������ݷ��u��Z�/�h�X�w1������}+lw�mc>Y���v�Q�������
>��YIlE���mNvGnV�[�'=#a�zFZ�nEv��
                                 �Z'�I��Y�x��w�5�����vM�ud�<�E[V���؜-����?��y���);�)�}�Gt�fώI����� ��Et���g����['����u�NY��V�a�W[Y�?��Ӎ�;�����+y�Q)�O靛���Iʏ@g+�G�e+��V0>$[AJH��
�#z/�Q!m�+?eTdTHAF�Q�
\�{Ã�                gT�3*�1*��R�F�Q!mT�@F
)h�Bڨ�6�]/0*��ƇRB�
)h�Bڨ�6*D��
h�Bʨ <Ȩ��6*D��
h�ַ��
�C�
)!F��Q!mT�@F�Q!eTdTHAF�Q���F��8����BJ�Q!mT�@F�Q!mT�@�R�F�Q!�k~6�(}����zz�������Vnu��ꕟ��^��J=D�7�z�D̤P��紺˵�D�N|�q�}��K�Х�{����F�c*G]SލE�Q�Lw#���+���`7xԕt�/W���J3N�'�+[;�p��rG�+3;�p���x���:���8M�חB�t'~B״�Z��14F_������  }e�Pzz1xa�(��~T���fX�Í�'`��� �&\j�
QaR�]VjHX��p�!*Xj�K
Q]Rۣ([R�v�q�0'�Cvq��
                        �����j�!VKP���j��O諞��WF?���֏B+�G�I���ڤ7����W-y��UK�R㪥N�qՒ_j\��&5�Zj�:<9�      AR㪥N�q�R�Ըj�/5�Zj�W-�I���ڤ�C�b¥�UK�R�%�Ըj�Mj\��&5�Zj�W-y��UK�R㪥N�qՒ_j\��&5�Zj�W-�I����R㪥N�q�R�Ըj�F�G@MS�����.Y�(�����r^(�ȓ�vS�Q[9~���+ö?���_�13O@wnWJ�'�6@�ūd�3U&��$j~�y�v�9][�haS�B�7Ϯ�4�<�v}�}��=���L�շ�!݌W������wi&|G��!:Ǩ�����$����?3Y�d���*K4�������3�Q��
������J>/�O���#                                                        .�
               ^}>�����m���۝�_6?����y����)irQ�pۋY����o���O���P!@���9#word/webSettings.xml��_O�0�w���w� ���Ab
                                                                                                           �c�~��ݠ��-���O�mbxa����r�v��9�|B ���a*�K�ׅx[�"��|�,z(�H,�7�&o`�
8EC���f����Ӱ�N��m=��j��X�r���80���hx@�u�c/X����tԚk�CY�@��8��9e���]@�耄Ur1��:��Gi7r����@�a�Ϙ
���-��8�K                                                                                  ɑ�)�9��1��d��~���][�����cP+��Q�לtp�r�m�
         � �ee-6/Ϗ<�����P!�ԗ��word/fontTable.xmlܒ���0���}cى��Yg��
k�4��tM���}���=�j�:�OI�ؚN���k%�W+Z�';$Z���LC�zg��;�n�i����n@Zo�Т�g��~���*�(LOY�����d7���/����`�5GU�8�
                                                                                                    GUW��+�
r"?�'n�E�1��}�$�Gm&F�6|��o�~%Ca�Ƅ/�S{�b��ƂL1v�]IY�v,�1�+�
G2�F'r�#8��刋�Y����8r����#So��i����?�i�?��P!��<�ndocProps/core.xml �(���QO�0��M���P`�L,Q���%&�h|���Vm�vc�{,��O���(,("r�29"r.{��dt�Ɖg�%�r ?���

                                                                                                          &�'������r�tv,
                                                                                                                        ��p)2!�@Pɸ�d�u5���3F
) C54˯�R�*5<k�@[�sN�$Tehk�J06t
                              %1�#��R�ĺVo�"tG6��0��%X%�1����N���j��րQ
                                                                     � ��Q�3kA���@�� Knk�^��XUUPMZ�������U��&+
�J�/�`���Ӿ(Z���wPWR3��G������";�с�
                                  b������}�ތh8��e�QK
���I�0{�m�<�ЏB?�W�]r3M��Yo46,O                    mz���
                                �۱7�?���P!��;%mdocProps/app.xml �(��R�N�0�#�Q��B�8�ҳeo
                                                                                      ǶlS�Ϧ�!���zG3k���7�C�Ζ�jY�Z锶m�o��u��$��Y,�#���_^�[pC�3���̻�cQv؋����N�B/��2�4Z⽓�=���Eq���*T
                                ?       ���>�WT99����ѓ�{oDB�2L��r�6�P�$L�{���7�b�+`c;�  �l:�L�?�Z�A���h)-�?k\tM�^On�a��
P�
�g��8��Cx�v�1d+��}{�TR�Pv�{aI�M�}ĭ��������,�N���B^~��5�"ٟL<�s3�ӬmQ���m
                                                                     �{�%_]-
                                                                            :���9�=}���PK!ߤ�lZ [Content_Types].xmlPK!���N
                                                                                                                         �_rels/.relsPK!B:O}��
�word/document.xmlPK!�d�Q�1�    word/_rels/document.xml.relsPK!��g��� �
                                                                       word/theme/theme1.xmlPK!Y��v
                                                                                                   �word/settings.xmlPK!K�qal
                                                                                                                             �rword/styles.xmlP!@���9#�"word/webSettings.xmlPK!�ԗ��$word/fontTable.xmlPK!��<�n�"&docProps/core.xmlPK!��;%m��(docProps/app.xmlPK

                                                                                                              �j+
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank You

I tried the below code

```
pdfWindow.document.write(
      "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " +
        encodeURI(pdfcontent) +
        "'></iframe>",
    );
    window.open('data:application/pdf,' + encodeURI(pdfcontent.toString()));
```

It is not opening. I tried using a sample PDF in URL using window.open but it opened in a different window.

Comment: @KJ  Hi , I am converting that using that blob code for javascript to get into that format . Is there any way i can convert that into a PDF format from Blob.

Comment: @K J Ok , So how to download and view the pdf file which is there in the blob

Comment: The whole pdf document is there in the blob and it is opening there

Comment: I tried with URL and downloading it from the client side but getting CORS error

Comment: Is there any other way we can read the PDF contents from blob ? Then after that i can easily convert that pdf content to get downloaded. have used the code mentioned in the question to read pdf files from blob.Is that the correct way because i am not getting the desired output after the conversion.

Comment: I researched but the only way to download PDF from Blob in React JS is this.

Comment: For other ways some or the other issues are cropping up.